# Time complexity for transposing a graph

Tags: c++, graph, time-complexity

I would like to get some help to analyze the time complexity of the following function.

The graphs stores all vertexes in the vector list. Each vertex has a vector which stores the vertex edges. This vector is called neighbors.

```
Graph
Graph::transpose() const
{
   Graph Graph_T;

   for( auto& vertex : list )
   {
      Graph_T.insert_vertex( vertex -> get_name() );
   }

   for( auto& vertex : list )
   {
      for( auto& edges : vertex -> neighbours )
      {
         Graph_T.insert_edge(edges,vertex );
      }
   }
   return Graph_T;  
}
```

The first for-loop is obviously |V| , where |V| is the number of vertexes.

The second for-loop is also |V| but has the third loop nestled inside. My Guess is that the third loop time complexity is |E|, where |E| is the number of edges in the Graph.

Summation:
The time complexity is /theta ( V+V+E) = /theta (E+V).

Is my analyze correct?

Comment: What is the time complexity of `insert_vertex` and `insert_edge`?

Comment: Both methods runs in constant time.

Answer (score 1):

I would say O(|V|^2) as there is a double for: the external one is done |V| times and the internal one is done at maximum |V| times.

Comment: That's true. But it could also be expressed using E, I think. +1

Comment: The external loop runes in O(V) and internal one runs in O(E) which mean that transpose() runs O(EV) and not in O(V^2).

Since E in worst case is equal to V^2, transpose() can also be expressed as O(V^3).